# Flow and custom Webpack loaders

Tags: javascript, webpack, flowtype

I use Webpack to build my React project with Flow types. I have configured Webpack to import SVG files using [svg-sprite-loader](https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader/) as such:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: ['svg-sprite-loader']
}
```

This allows me to "import" SVG files as such:

```
import letterCellSymbol from '../styles/icons/tool-letter.svg'
```

Then I can use the files in my React components like this:

```
<svg className="icon">
  <use xlinkHref={`#${letterCellSymbol.id}`} />
</svg>
```

This causes problems with Flow type checking, of course:

```
Error: src/components/Toolbox.jsx:70
 70: <use xlinkHref={`#${letterCellSymbol.id}`} />
                                          ^^ property `id`. Property not found in
 70: <use xlinkHref={`#${letterCellSymbol.id}`} />
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ String
```

What's the proper way to tell Flow that these SVG files export objects with the type `{id: string}` or simply ignore these errors entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I edited my `.flowconfig` file to include:

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='svg' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/helpers/SVGModule.js'
```

Then I created the file `./src/helpers/SVGModule.js` and entered:

```
/* @flow */
export default { id: '' }
```

This makes Flow think that any imported/required file that ends in `.svg` exports `{id:''}`, so the error is ignored. The downside is that files that don't exist are not reported as an error.

Sources that helped me solve this problem:

- [.flowconfig documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-extension-string-string)
- [GitHub Flow issue: How to use declarations to avoid "required module not found" errors? #2092](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2092)

Comment: For anyone trying to use this to help type React components with SVGR, here is when I wrote: `import {type StatelessFunctionalComponent} from 'react'; export const ReactComponent: StatelessFunctionalComponent<any> = () => 'svg'; export default ReactComponent;` Then I'm able to `import {ReactComponent as MySvg} from './some.svg';` and flow doesn't complain. The return string `'svg'` is arbitrary, it just needs to be something renderable by React.